# How to install psycopg2 on mac with virtualenv on Python3.6?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, virtualenv, psycopg2

I am running OSX 10.12.2 (16C67) and 3.6.0 inside virtualenv.

I have tested following.

```
➜  ~ brew services restart postgresql
Stopping `postgresql`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)

➜  ~ pg_config
BINDIR = /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/bin
DOCDIR = /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/share/doc/postgresql
HTMLDIR = /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/share/doc/postgresql
INCLUDEDIR = /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/include
PKGINCLUDEDIR = /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/include
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/include/server
LIBDIR = /usr/local/lib
PKGLIBDIR = /usr/local/lib/postgresql
LOCALEDIR = /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/share/locale
MANDIR = /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/share/man
SHAREDIR = /usr/local/share/postgresql
SYSCONFDIR = /usr/local/etc/postgresql
PGXS = /usr/local/lib/postgresql/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
CONFIGURE = '--disable-debug' '--prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1' '--datadir=/usr/local/share/postgresql' '--libdir=/usr/local/lib' '--sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc' '--docdir=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/share/doc/postgresql' '--enable-thread-safety' '--with-bonjour' '--with-gssapi' '--with-ldap' '--with-openssl' '--with-pam' '--with-libxml' '--with-libxslt' '--with-perl' '--with-tcl' '--with-tclconfig=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/lib' '--with-uuid=e2fs' 'CC=clang' 'LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib' 'CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include'
CC = clang
CPPFLAGS = -DFRONTEND -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -O2
CFLAGS_SL =
LDFLAGS = -L../../src/common -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs
LDFLAGS_EX =
LDFLAGS_SL =
LIBS = -lpgcommon -lpgport -lxslt -lxml2 -lpam -lssl -lcrypto -lgssapi_krb5 -lz -lreadline -lm
VERSION = PostgreSQL 9.6.1

➜  ~ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Checked that XCode tools are installed. But I keep getting errors when trying to install psycopg2. Any ideas what to do next.

** EDIT

I just tried to install it outside the virtualenv using same Python version and it installed without any issues.

```
➜  ~ pip3 install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for psycopg2 ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/Kimmo/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/49/47/2a/5c3f874990ce267228c2dfe7a0589f3b0651aa590e329ad382
Successfully built psycopg2
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.
```

6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Python 2 and Python 3 have a `pip` utility associated with them. Therefore, if you install both in the same directory the second installation runs the risk of overwriting the `pip` from the first one.

It's always safest to run `python2 -m pip` or `python3 -m pip` if you want to be sure which version you are running.

Once you've correctly activated a virtual environment, *its* `pip` should be the one that runs by default, ensuring that installation happens inside the virtual environment. If the virtualenv doesn't include pip you will find it more difficult ti install packages into your virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with my configuration `pip install -r requirements.txt` fails when using python3.

I solved this by running `pip uninstall -r requirements.txt` and then running `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: It seems there's some confusion about which `pip` will execute. This isn't good. Under these circumstances (assuming you know which `python` will run :-)) it's often better to use `python -m pip` instead

Comment: Ah never realised I could run pip like any other Python module with -m flag. Yes that might be better idea

Comment: Yes, it processes arguments just like `pip` and makes it easier to determine which one to use. But I suspect the real issue is having python2 and python3 installed in the same directory

Comment: If you want write an aswer with it and I accept. Else thanks with the help anyway.

Comment: Cool. It's probably also good to retain this answer, since others will undoubtedly be grateful for your suggestion of how to get rid of the wrong stuff.